# ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, npm

I have a nodejs application and I want to deploy it using docker.
I have the following structure for folders and files

```
/src
   /config
       status.js
       role.js
       index.js
   /routes
       user.routes.js
       product.routes.js
       index.js
   index.js
   Dockerfile
   package.json
   ... other files and folders
```

the content of `src/config/index.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  ...require("./status"),
  ...require("./role"),
};
```

The content of Dockerfile

```
FROM node:19-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

when I do `docker image build` I got the following error

```
 ---> Running in 2f2e6c84845b
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/src/config/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/src/config/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-26T09_17_19_235Z-debug-0.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm i' returned a non-zero code: 254
```

I tried to add `package.json` with empty json to every folder has `index.js` file and that worked fine. but does that make sense to add `package.json` to every folder.

Comment: It's looking for `package.json` in your config folder. You have it in your root folder.

Comment: I don't know why It's looking for `package.json` file in every folder even It exists in root folder

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to replace that PNG file with the plain-text error message?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  It seems like the Dockerfile might also be essential to understand what might be going wrong as well.